# Exception handling when using Python's subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, exception, subprocess

When dealing with open files, Python has the `with` syntax that makes sure the file closes when leaving the block - regardless of exceptions etc.

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    foo = f.read()
```

Since processes are resources too, I was wondering: is something similar possible or recommended when using `Popen`? For example, should [`Popen.kill(); Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) be run in a `finally` clause - assuming I don't mind blocking until the process finishes?

Comment: If you were running a version pre python 3.2. you could just define a class with the `__enter__` and `__exit__` magic methods to use `with`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from Python 3.2 `Popen` is a context manager.

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> Popen objects are supported as context managers via the with statement: on exit, standard file descriptors are closed, and the process is waited for.

This should do pretty much what you want.

This is the relevant part from `subprocess.py` from the standard lib
in Python 3.4:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    if self.stdout:
        self.stdout.close()
    if self.stderr:
        self.stderr.close()
    if self.stdin:
        self.stdin.close()
    # Wait for the process to terminate, to avoid zombies.
    self.wait()
```

Now you can do in Python 2.7

```
from subprocess import Popen

class MyPopen(Popen):

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.stdout:
            self.stdout.close()
        if self.stderr:
            self.stderr.close()
        if self.stdin:
            self.stdin.close()
        # Wait for the process to terminate, to avoid zombies.
        self.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MyPopen(['ls']) as p:
        print(p)
```

Comment: OK, cool. So it sounds like it's not a bad idea to do it in Python 2.7 as well, using `try...finally`

Comment: I added a Python 2.7 version by copying the code from python 3.4. Might need some testing though. ;)

Comment: @z0r: there is `subprocess32` module that you can install on Python 2.7 (it provides other improvements too. Though it might not work on non-POSIX systems).

Answer (score 5):

For 2.7 you could also use the [**`@contextlib.contextmanager`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def manage_process(process):
    try:
        yield process
    finally:
        for stream in [process.stdout, process.stdin, process.stderr]:
            if stream:
                stream.close()
        process.wait()
```

e.g:

```
with manage_process(Popen(['ls'])) as p:
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add just two custom methods to any class to implement comptability with `with` statement.

```
class CustomObject(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        """ This method execudes when entering block. """
        return thing_you_want_to_use

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        """ This method execudes on block exit. """
        # Tear things down.
```